# Is there any country in Europe that allows a foreign worker to invite his parents?

Tags: visas, work, family, working-visas

Most countries that I know don't consider parents as family members and don't allow a legal worker to take them with him/her (unlike taking the spouse or children) for the term of the contract. Are there any countries in Europe that allow that? If that helps, I'm talking about a legit IT employee.

Comment: In Germany, the authorities *may* allow parents in if that is necessary to avoid undue hardship. Basic language proficiency is required unless that would be undue hardship, too.